# Is it possible to override/extend onNewFolder in Alfresco?

Tags: directory, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco 5. I have create a custom type (parent type is cm:folder) and
added an entry for this type in the Document Library "Create" menu.
I would like to override the default folder create function so that I can do
some custom processing.
I would like to create some content within the new folder each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alfresco behaviour/policies for your requirement.

For creating policy you need to create below things.

1.Spring Bean in context file
2.One class which implements onCreateNode from org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies

For more information regarding policies read below blog written by Jeff Potts

http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/behaviors/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart from behaviour/policies easier option would be using rule and script.

- You can create a rule which will be executed on creation of new
  folder.
- Create alfresco java script which will do processing you required on creation of
  new folder.
- Hook up script with rule.